# Unir varios datos de una columna, según un parámetro/condición, en una fila usando Python (como un join o concatenar)

Tags: python, excel, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Debo hacer una unión de varios elementos (un concatenar o un join) del siguiente tipo de datos (ver imagén)...

[image: captura de pantalla del tipo de datos utilizados]

Lo anterior, debe quedar así...

[image: resultado deseado]

El dato numérico no interesa, por lo cual se puede eliminar u obviar, se requiere sólo los nombres en fila y en una sola cadena.
Obviamente, en Excel o en Sheets de Google se puede hacer con un join, pero son muchos datos y tomará mucho tiempo ir grupo por grupo (son más de 45 mil, dividido en varias hojas), así que me pregunto si existe alguna opción de hacer algún código en Python que haga esto más rápido. No existe problema en pasar/crear el archivo en CSV.

El patrón se repite en la columna, donde sólo varía el número de personas para cada código numérico que le acompaña.

*El dato "Total 76521930" y los otros parecidos, es sólo el resultado de la tabla dinámica, ya que se debió ordenar los datos para poder crear los grupos para así lego  hacer el JOIN o concatenar para cada grupo.*

Comment: ¿Qué has probado hasta ahora?

Comment: Le falta enfoque a la pregunta. Podrías enfocarla a generar un CSV, un archivo XSLX (o cualquier otro formato) o pasar los datos a la hoja de cálculo de Google pero quizás antes de eso primero debes enfocarte 1. Tomar los datos, 2. El algoritmo para hacer "un join o concatenar" y 3. Entregar el resultado en el formato que elijas.

Comment: Elier, por ahora, lo estoy haciendo en Sheets de Google con el JOIN pero toma mucho tiempo ir grupo por grupo, ya que cada grupo tiene distintos números de integrantes y en ello hay que tener ojo.  Rubén, puedo crear el CSV desde el excel o el Sheets de Google para luego trabajarlo en Python, pero no sé como debiera ser el código para que haga lo que requiero (esto se aprecia en la segunda imagen de la pregunta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es exactamente lo que pides, pero ya que estás usando Google Sheets, puedes hacerlo con fórmulas, independientemente del nº de integrantes de cada uno. Es una solución temporal.

Yo he hecho un conjunto de dato similar a los tuyos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, cada grupo tiene una cantidad de integrantes diferentes. En el `Campo3` mi fórmula es:

`=SI(IZQUIERDA(A2;5)="Total";DERECHA(A2;LARGO(A2)-6);"")`

Esto básicamente devuelve el nº de grupo, pero solo en aquellas filas de total. Si no, devuelve un valor en blanco.

En `Campo4` tengo la siguiente fórmula:

`=SI(A2="";D1&", "&B2;SI(B2="";D1;B2))`

Simplemente va concatenando los nombres de arriba con el que está a la izquierda. Así, el total de integrantes aparece concatenado en la última fila de cada grupo.

Luego es solamente filtrar en `Campo3` y desmarcar las celdas vacías:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y entonces obtendrías el resultado siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mío es a mano porque no tengo ni idea de Python, pero al menos dejarías de perder tiempo concatenando individualmente cada grupo.

Además, las fórmulas que yo he puesto se pueden usar perfectamente en Google Sheets.

E incluso puedes conectar un Excel a google Sheets (como si fuera una página web) y hacer una macro en VBA que te haga este proceso de manera automática (conectarse, descargar los datos, poner las fórmulas y filtrar).

No es la respuesta que esperabas, pero hasta que encuentres una solución en python al menos podrás utilizarla y ahorrar tiempo que si concatenas cada grupo a mano.

Comment: Y luego arrastro las fórmulas hacia abajo. Buena idea, gracias Elier, esta me sirve para lo que necesito, muchas gracias. Igual buscaré una solución para este problema pero en Python, para ir aprendiendo.